# Error: Cannot find module 'express-session '

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, express-session

got an error while implementing express session 
C:\Users\HARRY\Desktop\mean-stack-app>npm install express-session --save
npm WARN mean-stack-app@1.0.0 No repository field.

```
 + express-session@1.15.6
 added 4 packages in 5.1s


Error: Cannot find module 'express-session '
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HARRY\Desktop\mean-stack- 
app\app\passport\passport.js:3:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HARRY\Desktop\mean-stack- 
app\server.js:12:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
```

---

```
dependencies
"author": "Muhammad Haris",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
"body-parser": "^1.18.2",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"express-session": "^1.15.6",
"jquery": "^3.1.1",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.1",
"mongoose": "^5.0.17",
"morgan": "^1.9.0",
"passport": "^0.4.0",
"passport-facebook": "^2.1.1"
```

Comment: What is the used node.js version ? `node -v`

Comment: Can you share the file where you have used the `express-session` module?